# Include files in array - PHP

Tags: php

I have this code in main php file and I want to include 2 or more translation files

```
<?php
 $lang = array(
  'en' => array(
   include ('nav-translation/en.php');
   include ('home-translation/en.php');
  ),
  'lv' => array(
   include ('nav-translation/lv.php');
   include ('home-translation/lv.php');
  ),
 );
?>
```

and there is one of the files "nav-translation/en.php" that I want to include into main file

```
<?php
 "home" => "Home",
 "about" => "About me",
 "blog" => "Blog",
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<?php
"home" => Translator::t('app','en',"Home"),
"about" => Translator::t('app','en',"About me"),
"blog" => Translator::t('app','en',"Blog"),
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your array should be

```
 $lang = array(
  'en' => array(
   'nav-translation/en.php',
   'home-translation/en.php',
  ),
  'lv' => array(
   'nav-translation/lv.php',
   'home-translation/lv.php',
  ),
 );
```

and replace your code in  nav-translation/en.php to

```
return array(
 "home" => "Home",
 "about" => "About me",
 "blog" => "Blog"
 );
```

and to include that file you should write

```
 $en_nav = include_once($lang["en"][0]);
```

and use $en_nav to access home , about , blog keys in "nav-translation/en.php" file so if you need transaction of home key you only write $en_nav["home"]

Comment: I have one question. Where do I need to write $en_nav = include_once($lang["en"][0]); ?

Comment: in your main file under  $lang = array(
  'en' => array(
   'nav-translation/en.php',
   'home-translation/en.php',
  ),
  'lv' => array(
   'nav-translation/lv.php',
   'home-translation/lv.php',
  ),
 );