# Display array loop

Tags: php, html

I want to display my products that are in php array.
There is php array

```
<?php
    $products = array(
        "product1" => array(
            "productName" => "Product 1",
            "productPrice" => "19.34",
            "productDescription" => "This is product 1",
            "productThumb" => "image-product-1.png",
        ),
        "product2" => array(
            "productName" => "Product 2",
            "productPrice" => "5.32",
            "productDescription" => "This is product 2",
            "productThumb" => "image-product-2.png",
        ),
    );
?>
```

And I want to display it like this in html code, but without the description

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="productThumb"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="productName"></div>
    <div class="productPrice"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is really easy to achieve even with minimal knowledge.

Comment: wouldn't be related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52801356/1415724 would it?

Comment: You mean need to display the productName in "productName" div. right?

Comment: Yes i have done like this <div class="productName"><?php echo $product1["productName"]; ?></div> but i don't want to it manualy

Comment: @VinothRaja yes

Comment: @KristersDzintars  are you really want product-thumb as a text  or as an image? if image, go check my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy:-

```
<?php foreach($products as $product){?>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="productThumb"><img src="<?php echo $product['productThumb'];?>"></div>
        <div class="productName"><?php echo $product['productName'];?></div>
        <div class="productPrice"><?php echo $product['productPrice'];?></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this below code

```
<?php

     $products = array(
        "product1" => array(
            "productName" => "Product 1",
            "productPrice" => "19.34",
            "productDescription" => "This is product 1",
            "productThumb" => "image-product-1.png",
        ),
        "product2" => array(
            "productName" => "Product 2",
            "productPrice" => "5.32",
            "productDescription" => "This is product 2",
            "productThumb" => "image-product-2.png",
        ),
    );

    foreach($products as $product_data)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="product">
        <div class="productThumb"></div><?php echo $product_data['productThumb']; ?> </div>
        <div class="productName"> <?php echo $product_data['productName']; ?> </div>
        <div class="productPrice"> <?php echo $product_data['productPrice']; ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php
    }
?>
```